# Simplified regular expression matching in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to write a simple regular expression matching in `Scala` as an exercise. For simplicity I assume the strings to match are ASCII and the regexps consists of ASCII characters and two metacharacters: `.` and `*` only. (Obviously, I don't use any regexp library).

This is my simple and slow (exponential) solution.

```
def doMatch(r: String, s: String): Boolean = {
  if (r.isEmpty) s.isEmpty
  else if (r.length > 1 && r(1) == '*') star(r(0), r.tail.tail, s)
  else if (!s.isEmpty && (r(0) == '.' || r(0) == s(0))) doMatch(r.tail, s.tail)
  else false
}

def star(c: Char, r: String, s: String): Boolean = {
  if (doMatch(r, s)) true
  else if (!s.isEmpty && (c == '.' || c == s(0))) star(c, r, s.tail)
  else false
}
```

Now I would like to improve it. Could you suggest a simple polynomial solution in ~10-15 lines of "pure" Scala code ?

Comment: @Lindrian No, this is not a homework.

Comment: I think the reason no one has posted an answer is that this isn't a trivial thing to do. The normal method for doing this is converting the regular expression into an NFA, and then using the [subset construction algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to convert the NFA into a DFA. The fact that you have the `.` wildcard character is really what makes it complicated in your case. I don't think you'll be able to do this in 10-15 lines.

Comment: Check this video out--- seems like this is what you're after: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sTWutdffY4

Comment: Seems like it can solved by [something like that](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483724/178988), but with 2 point of rollback - first for repeating concrete char and second for repeating a dot.